# Is it possible to execute a task inside Google App Engine taskqueue?

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue

I want to do a unittest on a function inside Google App Engine taskqueue. I would like to know if there is any method by which we can execute the tasks in taskqueue so as to test whether it yields the desired output.

Comment: can't you enqueue it to the queue and execute it from the queue?

Comment: In my original code, countdown for taskqueue is 10 minutes. But I want to unittest the functionality I have written inside the task which.

Comment: does not matter the countdown, you can deque the task and just post to the url with the params https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting#Python_Writing_task_queue_tests
http://googleappengine.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/taskqueue_stub.py

Comment: Yes. Thats the best option available and testing post to url with params can be done by handler testing in Google App Engine [https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/handlertesting](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/handlertesting). Can you please add your comment as the answer so that it can be useful for others too? @marcadian

Comment: done, posted as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to manually deque the task from the queue and post to the url with all the params. Check these doc
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting#Python_Writing_task_queue_tests
http://googleappengine.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/taskqueue_stub.py

Comment: The TaskQueueServiceStub constructor has a param auto_task_running which suggests there could be a way to have the tasks executed by the stub as they are queued, but I have not been successful in using it. http://gae-pydoc.appspot.com/google.appengine.api.taskqueue.taskqueue_stub.TaskQueueServiceStub

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632809/gae-unit-testing-taskqueue-with-testbed for an example of how to manually execute the tasks.